# I want to change url after changing locale (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, url, routes, localization, middleware

```
Route.php //for route translation
return [   
   "company"  =>  "company/{company}",
];

My Route 
       Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.company'),'App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\CompanyController@show')->name('companypage');
My Controller
    public function show(Request $request ,Company $company)
   {
      $lang = LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale(); //current locale using mcamara/laravel package
      $lang=str_replace("zh","tc",$lang);
      $column = 'slug_' . $lang;
      $page = $company->slug_en ?? "";
      return view('frontend.company.companypage',compact('company','page'));
       
   }
```

My url before changing locale
http://127.0.0.1:8000/zh/company/company-zh
My url after changing locale
http://127.0.0.1:8000/kr/company/company-zh

```
[my route model binding][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4FJH.png

[my url before and after changing locale][2][3]

  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNtx2.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWwez.png

> I tried many ways but i have no idea how to change url after changing locale through middleware. please suggest solutions.
```

Comment: Read the [docs](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization). You don't have to set the locale. Just get a localized URL and go there.

Comment: ``` $url=LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL(LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale(),'company/'.$company->$column);
return redirect($url)->with(compact('company','page'));
i try to changed this and url is correct but redirection will loop and my site crash